# Sort grouping by ID while keeping slice positions by index using sort package

Tags: sorting, go, slice

I was wondering if it's possible to do a group sort while using the index to figure out the position in that slice range of structs using the same ids.

So essentially I have this piece of code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type (
    Column struct {
        ID string
        Name string
    }

    ByIDAndIndex []Column
)

func (c ByIDAndIndex) Len() int { return len(c) }
func (c ByIDAndIndex) Swap(i, j int) { c[i], c[j] = c[j], c[i] }
func (c ByIDAndIndex) Less(i, j int) bool {
    if c[i].ID == c[j].ID {
        return i > j
    }

    return i < j
}

func main() {   
    columns := []Column{
        Column{
            "1",
            "Red Apple",
        },      
        Column{
            "1",
            "Yellow Apple",
        },
        Column{
            "1",
            "Bismarck Apple",
        },
        Column{
            "2",
            "Orange",
        },
        Column{
            "1",
            "Anna Apple",
        },
    }

    sort.Sort(ByIDAndIndex(columns))

    for _, c := range columns {
        fmt.Println(c.ID, c.Name)
    }

}
```

Which outputs:

```
1 Bismarck Apple
1 Yellow Apple
1 Red Apple
2 Orange
1 Anna Apple
```

But I want it to output:

```
1 Bismarck Apple
1 Yellow Apple
1 Red Apple
1 Anna Apple
2 Orange
```

Since the "Anna Apple" is the same ID. It still holds the last position w/ the rest of the same IDs. One way I thought of getting around this is to simply write my own sort function that allocates a new slice. Iterates through the supplied slice append the first items, looks for any other items with the same ID and append them into the new slice. Go to the next item in the supplied, check if that ID has already been added or not, and repeat.

I wasn't sure if the supplied Sort interface would be efficient or not for this out of the box since it appears to quit before it really finishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but the `less()` function must tell if one element is less than the other.

If you primarily want to sort by `ID`, you have to return `c[i].ID < c[j].ID` if the IDs are not equal.

For example:

```
func (c ByIDAndIndex) Less(i, j int) bool {
    if c[i].ID != c[j].ID {
        return c[i].ID < c[j].ID
    }

    return i > j
}
```

Also note that using the passed indices for further comparison is not a deterministic order among equal IDs, it depends on the actual sort implementation / algorithm. So the above may result in different orders, what it guarantees is only the proper sort where ID is different.

You should use the stable sorting. Also since you're sorting a slice, you may use [`sort.SliceStable()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#SliceStable) so you only have to provide the `less()` function. Stable sorting guarantees that elements which are "equal" will not be switched / reordered with each other.

```
type Column struct {
    ID   string
    Name string
}

func main() {
    columns := []Column{
        // ...
    }

    sort.SliceStable(columns, func(i, j int) bool {
        return columns[i].ID < columns[j].ID
    })

    for _, c := range columns {
        fmt.Println(c.ID, c.Name)
    }
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/---0H6SSotd)):

```
1 Red Apple
1 Yellow Apple
1 Bismarck Apple
1 Anna Apple
2 Orange
```

If stable sorting is not what you want, and you really want to decide order based on the original indices when IDs are the same, you have to store the indices prior to sorting them, because the sorting algorithm will rearrange items and the original index will not be available anymore, and index of the same element may change multiple times during the sort operation.

Comment: I should have mention ID was completely ambiguous (could be UUID for instance), but I got your message as far as the index not being a reliable source of sorting. I'll have to shoehorn in another method of giving it the ability to order by if that's the case or write something out of the box like I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the answer btw, it did set me on the right track very least.